# Problem subsetting a string from a filename

Tags: r, regex, substring, pattern-matching

I have an issue with extracting a pattern from strings in R.

I have a list of file names that includes path and I need to extract a small subset of the name from the path to assign to another vector. I can't get the proper pattern definition to extract the desired part.

Here is some examples of file names. I have a list of 500+ therefore, the sub function needs to be generic.

```
files = c("G:\\Conservation\\Monitoring\\Conditions physico-chimiques\\CTD\\CODES_R\\Data\\CTD_parc_marin\\2009\\odf\\CTD_2009099_BSM2AMONT_1_DN.ODF",
"G:\\Conservation\\Monitoring\\Conditions physico-chimiques\\CTD\\CODES_R\\Data\\CTD_parc_marin\\2011\\odf\\CTD_2011PSSL_42_1_DN.ODF",
"G:\\Conservation\\Monitoring\\Conditions physico-chimiques\\CTD\\CODES_R\\Data\\CTD_parc_marin\\2011\\odf\\CTD_2011PSSL_10_1_DN.ODF",
"G:\\Conservation\\Monitoring\\Conditions physico-chimiques\\CTD\\CODES_R\\Data\\CTD_parc_marin\\2022\\odf\\CTD_2022PSSL_202201017ESTMARAVAL_1_DN.odf")
```

The patterns I am looking to extract are these:

```
pattern = c("BSM2AMONT_1_DN",
            "PSSL_42_1_DN",
            "PSSL_10_1_DN",
            "ESTMARAVAL_1_DN")
```

So far, I have this function:

```
pattern <- sub(".*\\d{4,7}([A-Z]|\\d{9})(.*)\\.(ODF|odf)", "\\2", files)
```

This works almost perfectly, except for the last example where I get "STMARAVAL_1_DN" instead of the desired "ESTMARAVAL_1_DN".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the desired result? Just the patterns in your `pattern` vector in the same order they occur in the `files` vector, perhaps with an `NA` or empty string is the pattern isn't present? Or the `pattern` vector is your desired result, not part of the input?

Comment: One potential simplification would be `files = basenames(files)` to strip off all the directories and start with just the file names.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't know the basenames fonction. That will go in straight in my tool box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
sub(".*\\d{4,7}_?(?:([A-Z])|\\d{9})(.*)\\.(ODF|odf)", "\\1\\2", files)
# [1] "BSM2AMONT_1_DN"  "PSSL_42_1_DN"    "PSSL_10_1_DN"    "ESTMARAVAL_1_DN"
```

I changed `([A-Z]|\\d{9})` to `(?:([A-Z])|\\d{9})`: the `?:` means to not capture a backreference, but then I capture the letter (to add it back into the replacement string `"\\1\\2"`). I also added `_?` before it in order to fix the first element of the results.